# Setting a NEW environment variable with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to set a new environment variable with CMake. Said environment variable does not exist prior to calling `cmake` and I don't need it to exist after my script has run. The problem is that I can modify existing environment variables, but I cannot create a new environment variable.

Here's a test I did:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

No output.

In CMake script:

```
message(STATUS "$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

No output.

In shell:

```
$ echo $LANGUAGE
en_CA:en
```

In CMake script:

```
message(STATUS "$ENV{LANGUAGE}")
en_CA:en
```

Obviously I can display an existing variable without issues, the problem is when I try to add a new one. Here's the second test I did:

In CMake script:

```
set(ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} "potato")
message(STATUS "$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}")
```

No output

In CMake script:

```
set(ENV{'LANGUAGE'} "$ENV{LANGUAGE}:potato")
message(STATUS "$ENV{LANGUAGE}")
```

Output:

```
en_CA:en:potato
```

This is problematic to me. How can I go about setting a NEW environment variable?

Comment: It should be no quotes around environment variable name, see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) for `set` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I now feel very stupid.

Answer (score 4):

As @Tsyvarev pointed out, there should not be quotes around `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `set(ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} "potato")`