# How to set environment variable MAKEFLAGS in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, makefile

I am trying to compile some code which is managed with Cmake with `make`, and I have noticed that when I use cmake 3.25.1, I do not get "Entering directory ..." messages from `make`; but when I use cmake 3.14.3, I get these messages.

I would like to suppress these messages regardless of the cmake version used. So, I found [cmake: How to suppress "Entering directory" messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449472/cmake-how-to-suppress-entering-directory-messages) where it says

> You can use
>
> ```
> MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
> ```

... which, I gather, is an environment variable that `make` would read.

So, as per [Setting a NEW environment variable with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795001/setting-a-new-environment-variable-with-cmake), I wrote at the start of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(ENV{MAKEFLAGS} "--no-print-directory")
```

... then re-ran `cmake`, then ran `make`, and ... no effect, I still get:

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/src/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/c/src/build'
...
```

So, how can I set this `MAKEFLAGS`environment variable in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, so `make` can see it, and perform without these printouts? Note that I would prefer NOT setting this variable permanently in my shell environment (MINGW64 `bash`), so I would like to handle this in `CMakeLists.txt` alone.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389513/cmake-environmental-variables

Looks like CMake is being deliberately stupid, as always.

Comment: No it's not stupid. It would be stupid if `CMake` would permanently change environment variables. You would then be afraid to run `cmake -S. -Bbuild` on any random `CMakeLists.txt` file without checking it first. This is useful, when for example, you wish to change the `PATH` variable so that it uses a specific program shipped with your repository and not the system one (like a compiler for example).